# MySQL - Auto/Schedual SQL Updating Tables

Tags: mysql, database

I am not database engineering. But I have a question about the possibility of an issue about the MySQL database.

Is it possible to write SQL to get the data from several tables and then use these data (what we get) to updated a new table?
Also, this work should be scheduled daily.

The reason why I ask this question is because I am in this situation:
Our IT department has maintained a big database, but the database/tables are not meet our department's business need (we only have read permission). Our department has a small database (have all the permission), which we can use custom SQL to create some special table and updated them by daily.

So go back to the question, it is possible to set up the SQL and schedule it to make sure these SQL keep updating our tables?

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to write SQL to get the data from several tables and
>   then use these data (what we get) to updated a new table?

Yes it is possible. You can use a `UPDATE .. JOIN` construct to get the data from several table using `SELECT` statement and then `JOIN` with that inline view and perform the update operation to your other table.

**Example:**

```
UPDATE Your_Table a 
    JOIN (
         //Select query to get data from multiple other tables
    ) xxx ON a.some_column = xxx.some_matching_column
SET a.column_c = xxx.column_c;
```

> Also, this work should be scheduled daily

Sure, use [MySQL Event Schedular](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)